# how to use the 'choice' in argparse.ArgmentParser

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

```
self.parser.add_argument('--data_type',
                             help='the type of current data',
                             type=str,
                             choices=['image_train','image_test','depth_train','depth_test'],
                             default='image_train')
```

I declared a 'data_type', there are four choices of this argument, and the default is 'image_train', and I can use it like below:

```
train_dataset=MyDataSet(self.opt.dataset_folder,
                            self.opt.data_type,
                            image_transforms)
```

but the data_type  is always 'image_train', but if i want to change it to 'depth_train', how can i write it

Comment: I don't see the connection between your piece of `argparse` code, and the `MyDataSet` call.   I wonder if you even understand what `argparse` is for or what `commandline arguments` are.  What is the `self` class?  Where is the script the runs `self.parser.parse_args()`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste my complete code.

Comment: class Trainer(object):
    def __init__(self,options):
        self.opt=options
        train_dataset=MyDataSet(self.opt.dataset_folder,
                                self.opt.data_type,
                                image_transforms)
        train_loader=DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=4,num_workers=0)
        train_gt_dataset=MyDataSet(self.opt.dataset_folder,
                                   self.opt.data_type)

Comment: Put that in the question.  Code incomments is hard to read

Comment: Where does `options` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know to add my code in the comment. So I can only ask a new question. Looking forward to your precious guidance